# HTML5 Canvas Animation Flickering

Tags: javascript, html, animation, html5-canvas

I'm making an HTML5 game with animations. However, I am getting uncontrollable flickering from the animations as seen here: [image]

Here is an example of one of my animation functions:

```js
function Player(bullets, missiles) {
  this.missiles = missiles;
  this.missileCount = 4;
  this.bullets = bullets;
  this.angle = 0;
  this.position = {x: 200, y: 200};
  this.velocity = {x: 0, y: 0};
  this.img = new Image()
  this.img.src = 'assets/player/flappy-cat/flying/frame-1.png';
  this.width = 64;
  this.height = 64;
  this.state = "flying";
  this.timer = 0;
  this.frame = 'frame-1';

  var self = this;
  self.animate = function(time)
  {
    self.timer += time;
    if(self.timer > MS_PER_FRAME)
    {
      self.timer = 0;
      if(self.state = "flying")
      {
        switch(self.frame)
        {
          case 'frame-1':
            self.frame = 'frame-2';
            self.img.src = img1;
            break;
          case 'frame-2':
            self.frame = 'frame-3';
            self.img.src = img2;
            break;
          case 'frame-3':
            self.frame = 'frame-4';
            self.img.src = img3;
            break;
          case 'frame-4':
            self.frame = 'frame-5';
            self.img.src = img4;
            break;
          case 'frame-5':
            self.frame = 'frame-6';
            self.img.src = img5;
            break;
          case 'frame-6':
            self.frame = 'frame-7';
            self.img.src = img6;
            break;
          case 'frame-7':
            self.frame = 'frame-8';
            self.img.src = img7;
            break;
          case 'frame-8':
            self.frame = 'frame-1';
            self.img.src = img8;
            break;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        switch(self.frame)
        {
          case 'frame-1':
            self.frame = 'frame-2';
            self.img.src = 'assets/enemies/flappy-cat/hit/frame-2.png';
            break;
          case 'frame-2':
            self.frame = 'frame-1';
            self.img.src = 'assets/enemies/flappy-cat/hit/frame-1.png';
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

I have an update function where the animation function is called:

```js
var self = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    self.animate(elapsedTime);
  }, 1000
  );
```

I then render the animation:

```js
Player.prototype.render = function(elapasedTime, ctx, camera) {
  //var offset = this.angle * 23;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(this.position.x, this.position.y);
  //ctx.drawImage(this.img, 48+offset, 57, 23, 27, -12.5, -12, 23, 27);
  ctx.drawImage(this.img, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
  ctx.restore();
}
```

Then render everything in my app.js file:

```js
function render(elapsedTime, ctx) {

  // TODO: Render background
  // Includes background repeats every 1000 pixels so the level lasts longer
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(-camera.position.x, 0);
  ctx.drawImage(backgrounds[2], 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.restore();

  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(-camera.position.x, 0);
  ctx.drawImage(backgrounds[1], 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.restore();

  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(-camera.position.x, 0);
  ctx.drawImage(backgrounds[0], 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.restore();

  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(-camera.position.x, -camera.position.y);
  renderWorld(elapsedTime, ctx, camera);
  ctx.restore();


  // Render the GUI without transforming the
  // coordinate system
  renderGUI(elapsedTime, ctx);
}

/**
  * @function renderWorld
  * Renders the entities in the game world
  * IN WORLD COORDINATES
  * @param {DOMHighResTimeStamp} elapsedTime
  * @param {CanvasRenderingContext2D} ctx the context to render to
  */
function renderWorld(elapsedTime, ctx, camera) {
    
    // Render the bullets
    bullets.render(elapsedTime, ctx);

    // Render the missiles
    //missiles.forEach(function(missile) {
    //  missile.render(elapsedTime, ctx);
    //});

    // Render the player
    player.render(elapsedTime, ctx, camera);

    // Render the flappy monsters
    flappyMonsters.forEach(function(FlappyMonster){
      FlappyMonster.onload
      FlappyMonster.render(elapsedTime, ctx);
    });

    // Render the flappy cats
    skulls.forEach(function(Skull){
      Skull.render(elapsedTime, ctx);
    });

    // Render the flappy dragons
    flappyDragons.forEach(function(FlappyDragon){
      FlappyDragon.render(elapsedTime, ctx);
    });

    // Render the flappy grumpys
    flappyGrumpys.forEach(function(FlappyGrumpy){
      FlappyGrumpy.render(elapsedTime, ctx);
    });

    // Render the flappy grumpys
    flappyBirds.forEach(function(FlappyBird){
      FlappyBird.render(elapsedTime, ctx);
    });
}
```

I *am* using window.requestAnimationFrame in addition to a backbuffer. So neither of those are the problem.

I have also tried putting img.onload before my draw functions but those cause my sprites to disappear.

It is also worth noting that when I slow the animation down to 1/24th, you can see the flickering is caused by a temporary disappearance of the sprite as it is switching to a different frame. It does not happen at any particular frame though - the frames where this occurs is different every time.

I have tried just about every solution on the first three pages of Google so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Store one img element per state and use it instead of changing their src every frame. Even when cached it will take some asynchronous time to load. An other and probably preferred way would be to use sprites and the cropping options of drawImage.

Comment: If by that you mean put the path to the image in each case of the switch statement, that is how I had it previously and it made no difference.

Comment: No I mean store an Image object or `<img>` element per state. Set their src at init and don't change their path ever during the game. You could then have a currentImage property on your objects, pointing to the desired Image object. Or you could load sprites containing all the states of each personna in one image and only save the correct coordinates to crop with drwImage. The latest is preferred but implies a refactoring of your drawing function.

Comment: That fixed it! I just had to pre load all my images into an init function than pass them until each individual object. Thanks so much, been trying to fix this all week!